# Python, pinax, django, windows AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call_subprocess'

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv, pinax

I installed pinax on windows

after trying to create a project I got this error:

```
(mysite) C:\virtualenvs\mysite>pinax-admin setup_project mypinax
Created project mypinax
Installing project requirements...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\Scripts\pinax-admin-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Pinax==0.9a2', 'console_scripts', 'pinax-admin')()
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 105, in execute_from_command_line
    runner.execute()
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 94, in execute
    self.loader.load(command).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\base.py", lin
e 45, in run_from_argv
    self.handle(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\commands\setup_project.py", line 66, in handle
self.setup_project(args[0], options["base"], options)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\commands\setup_project.py", line 134, in setup_project
    installer.install_reqs(not options["allow_no_virtualenv"])
  File "c:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\commands\setup_project.py", line 207, in install_reqs
    pip.call_subprocess([
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call_subprocess'
```

I would be thankful for any help.
By the way I am using python 2.7.3 and the latest stable pinax version

Comment: Which version of django are you running? I believe Pinax's current state is working with 1.3 out the box, but more problematic with 1.4 - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pinax-users/MlNd98HQ4jI

Answer (score 12):

You have new version of **pip**, the function `pip.call_subprocess` has been moved to `pip.util.call_subprocess`. See: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/464

Just replace the string in

`C:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\commands\setup_project.py`

Before executing the pinax-admin