# What are the different options to install pinax(0.9a) inclusive requirements?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pinax

I tried the classical way with `pip install Pinax` and then install the requirements base.txt, but this does not work?

What are other options to install a working pinax(0.9) base project inclusive requirements?

**UPDATE:**

Thats the exception installing it the "proper" way...

```
Created project mysite
Installing project requirements...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\Scripts\pinax-admin-script
.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Pinax==0.9a2', 'console_scripts', 'pinax-admin')()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\lib\site-packages\pinax\co
re\management\__init__.py", line 105, in execute_from_command_line
    runner.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\lib\site-packages\pinax\co
re\management\__init__.py", line 94, in execute
    self.loader.load(command).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\lib\site-packages\pinax\co
re\management\base.py", line 45, in run_from_argv
    self.handle(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\lib\site-packages\pinax\co
re\management\commands\setup_project.py", line 66, in handle
    self.setup_project(args[0], options["base"], options)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\lib\site-packages\pinax\co
re\management\commands\setup_project.py", line 134, in setup_project
    installer.install_reqs(not options["allow_no_virtualenv"])
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Django\lol\mysite-env\lib\site-packages\pinax\co
re\management\commands\setup_project.py", line 207, in install_reqs
    pip.call_subprocess([
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call_subprocess'
```

Comment: pip usually installs all the requirements. that's wierd

Comment: yes it is!!! but when i follow the installation routine i just get error messages en mass...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250317/python-pinax-django-windows-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute). According to [Ilja Sucharev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687173/ilja-sucharev) it is due to the newer version of pip. So you need to change pip.call_subprocess to pip.util.call_subprocess to your virtualenv_project/lib/site-packages/pinax/core/management/commands/setup_project.py

Answer (score 5):

You don't install Pinax anymore.

Prior to project templates in Django, Pinax provided this functionality with bundled started projects.

To get a pinax starter project now, you would do something like:

```
pip install Django
django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/zipball/master <project_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pip or download and unpackage Pinax manually.

```
$ virtualenv mysite-env
$ source mysite-env/bin/activate
(mysite-env)$ pip install Pinax
```

OR

You can download a project from pypi and install it manually.

Errors may occur because you have a new version of Pip. The function `pip.call_subprocess` has been moved to `pip.util.call_subprocess`. See: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/464. Just replace the string in `C:\virtualenvs\mysite\lib\site-packages\pinax\core\management\commands\setup_project.py` before executing the pinax-admin; e.g., `(mysite-env)$ pinax-admin setup_project mysite`